# how to get the featured image in wordpress post view fishpig integration dynamically

Tags: layout, magento-1, third-party-module, wordpress

I am currently using the following xml to try and display a banner image at the top of the post view in the fishpig integration of magento and wordpress.

```
 <wordpress_post_view>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="wordpress/post_view" name="bannerslider" template="wordpress/post/banner.phtml">
        </reference>
 </wordpress_post_view>
```

how would I retrieve the url of the featured image in either the banner.phtml file or in the xml above so that I can display a dynamic featured image at the top of the wordpress post view page.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your banner.phtml file.

```
 <?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getFullSizeImage() ?>"/>
 <?php endif; ?>
```